# Return single row on case statement on left outer joined table

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, left-join, case

I have the following (simplified) tables

**Table Products**

```
ID
Title
```

**Table Data_Tags**

```
ID
ForeignID
Tag
```

There are two tags added for product ID 1: 'solid' and 'strong'

Query below will return 2 rows and if I add DISTINCT it will only return 1 row as expected.

```
SELECT  Products.ID, Products.Title
FROM    Products LEFT OUTER JOIN Data_Tags ON Products.ID = Data_Tags.ForeignID
WHERE  (Products.ID = 1)
```

I would like to add a CASE statement to the query to calculate a specific relevance to certain keywords

```
CASE WHEN CONTAINS(Data_tags.tag, 'solid') THEN 100 ELSE 0 END AS TagsMatch
```

Query will become this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Products.ID, Products.Title, CASE WHEN CONTAINS(Data_tags.tag, 'solid') THEN 100 ELSE 0 END AS TagsMatch
FROM    Products LEFT OUTER JOIN Data_Tags ON Products.ID = Data_Tags.ForeignID
WHERE  (Products.ID = 1)
```

When running the query it will return two rows, which makes perfect sense as it will output 100 for tag 'solid' (match) and 0 for tag 'strong' (no match)

However I am unsure on how to modify the query to only return a single row with value 0 if none of the related tags are a match and 100 if any of the related tags is a match.

I would also like to avoid subqueries to keep performance best as possible.

I am using MS SQL Server 2014.

Please advise. Thank you very much!

Comment: Use `Max(CASE....)` along with `Group By Product.ID`

Comment: When I try this an error occurs: 'Full-text predicates cannot appear in an aggegrate expression. Place the aggregate expression in a subquery'

Comment: You used the wrong tag. Rather tag `SQL-SERVER` and remove `MySQL`

Comment: My bad. Corrected the tag.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to find a solution for your question. It turns out 1000111 was correct. You cannot use Contains without full-text search... If you replace Contains() with like I think this should solve your problem. Here is what I did:

```
Declare @Products table 
  (ID int,
Title varchar(50))

insert into @Products values (1, 'Test')

Declare @Data_Tags table 
(ID int,
ForeignID int,
Tag varchar(50))

insert into @Data_Tags values (1, 1, 'solid')
insert into @Data_Tags values (2, 1, 'strong')


SELECT DISTINCT Products.ID, Products.Title, max(CASE WHEN Data_tags.tag like '%stttt%' THEN 100 ELSE 0 END) AS TagsMatch
FROM  @Products Products LEFT OUTER JOIN @Data_Tags Data_Tags ON Products.ID = Data_Tags.ForeignID
WHERE  (Products.ID = 1)
group by Products.ID, Products.Title
```

The above return 0, when you change '%stttt%' to '%solid%' it returns 100.

Let me know if this helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Products.ID, Products.Title, max(CASE WHEN Data_tags.tag = 'solid' THEN 100 ELSE 0 END) AS TagsMatch
FROM  @Products Products 
LEFT OUTER JOIN @Data_Tags Data_Tags 
    ON Products.ID = Data_Tags.ForeignID
WHERE  (Products.ID = 1)
group by Products.ID, Products.Title
```